# How can I find the number of points I have received in a particular tag?

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-badges

I want to know the number of points that I have in a particular tag, say [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), to monitor when I will cross the 400 point barrier and get the silver tag badge. I searched, but I wasn't able to find anywhere the points for a particular tag.

Comment: Have you checked the "tags" section in your profile? It filter them by vote, so I suppose that's what you want

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yes, Wow, i don't know how i missed that. Thanx a lot. :).. Can you post it as an answer so that i can accept it..

Comment: You know you can track particular badges, too?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How?

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258350/248731

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thats even better. Thanx..